# Почему объединение строк происходит с новой строки?

Tags: python, pandas

Считываю файл, провожу некоторые манипуляции с данными.
Затем, нужно создавать строки путем объединения

```
amount = sub_string + plus_time
```

Но почему-то объединение происходит с новой строки.

Вот так выводится в `print`:

```
1 253 

.00:00:00
```

Файл находится [здесь](https://transfiles.ru/ouzyb). Вот код:

```
plus_time ="00:00:00"

name_file = "stbnz.csv"
file = open(name_file, "r")
contents = file.readlines()


for i in range(0, len(contents)):
    splitted_text = contents[i].split(",")
    sub_string = contents[i][len(splitted_text[0])+1:]
    sub_string = sub_string.replace(".", "")
    sub_string = sub_string.replace(",", ".")
    sub_string = sub_string.replace("M", "")
    amount = sub_string + plus_time

    print(amount)
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример того, что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: Потому, что строка при чтении файла содержит знак перевода строки на конце '\n'

Comment: Вот так хочу: 1 253.00:00:00

Comment: разобрался нужна функция strip()

Answer (score 2):

```
plus_time =".00:00:00"

df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\stbnz.csv", header=None, names=["Date", "Val"])

df["Val"] = (df
             ["Val"]
             .str.replace(r"[,M]", "")
             .str.replace(".", " ", regex=False)
             + plus_time)
```

---

результат:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
                 Date             Val
0    25.06.2020 (май)  1 253.00:00:00
1    26.05.2020 (апр)  1 267.00:00:00
2    29.04.2020 (мар)    672.00:00:00
3    25.03.2020 (фев)    594.00:00:00
4    27.02.2020 (янв)   -340.00:00:00
..                ...             ...
121       27.05.2010     656.00:00:00
122       29.04.2010     567.00:00:00
123       26.03.2010     321.00:00:00
124       26.02.2010     269.00:00:00
125       29.01.2010       2.00:00:00

[126 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Можно построчно сделать, так как не всегда нужно добавлять + plus_time. Хорошо бы понять почему происходит перенос строки.

Comment: @inquirer, в Pandas использование циклов считается моветоном в 99% случаев, поэтому прежде чем использовать цикл нужно убедиться, что без него никак. Объясните как нужно обрабатывать разные варианты строк и приведите небольгой пример того, что вы хотите получить в результате. Наверняка существует элегантное решение без использования циклов